# How can I cast "A" to "A conforms to protocol B"?

Tags: ios, swift

I declared protocol and extension like this,

```
protocol FooProtocol: class {

}

extension FooProtocol where Self: UIView {

    func changeAlphaToZero() {

        self.alpha = 0

    }

}
```

and I tried to use `changeAlphaToZero()` like this, (just a example.)

```
class MyClass {

    func setViewAlphaToZeroIfNeeded(view: UIView) {

        if let v = view as? FooProtocol {

            v.changeAlphaToZero() // Compile Error "FooProtocol is not a subtype of UIView."

        }

    }

}
```

Can I cast a `view` to "UIView conforms to FooProtocol" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like :

```
protocol FooProtocol {
  func changeAlphaToZero()
}


extension UIView: FooProtocol {

    func changeAlphaToZero() {

        self.alpha = 0

    }

}
```